# Vanilla kernel .deb pakage

Tags: 10.10, kernel

I want to install the vanilla kernel of Ubuntu 10.10, through the .deb package, but it is not compiling.
What's wrong? Is there a PPA?

Please help!

Comment: Even if you did install a "pure vanilla" kernel, your Ubuntu system is unlikely to even boot with it. Some level of configuration is necessary. Can you be more specific about what you are trying to accomplish here? Why do you want this in the first place? Maybe we can suggest something more useful if we know what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: See related question on U&L: [Is there a vanilla kernel configuration?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/17534)

Answer (score 4):

Try looking at [this link](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds). It does seem that Ubuntu is offering Unmodified Mainline Kernel (I hope that this is what you mean by Vanilla Kernel).